# Persistent R session in R shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I have a shiny App with around 5 GB data load in global.R. For the first App user the app page load time is around 3 to 4 mins as all the global data have to be read from the disk during app initiation.

But for subsequent users (second or third user) the page load is immediate as the app uses the previously loaded global data in memory.

Is there a way to make the Shiny App's R process to be persistent in Memory even if all the users log-out. So that whenever a new user access the app it will load immediately ?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are using the `.RData` binary representaton of the data, this is much faster than most files to read, but still slow.

Therefore, have you tried running an `RServe` session? (https://www.rforge.net/Rserve/). This could have your data avaliable within it, and then passing the relevant queries/commands to retrieve the data.

The alternative is a faster instantiating dataset, maybe as an `ffdf` file.

Comment: Thanks NJBurgo.  I will test the ffdf file format as well as Rserve and will comment back in a day, with benchmark values.